# Sails.JS cannot find a route when redirecting

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I try to implement an login process correctly, i'm using a server render view approch for the frontend. Based on what a sails.js offical documentation says about setting routes, so in my routes.js, i have this :

```
module.exports.routes = {

  '/': {
    view: 'login'
  },
  // Server render HTML views

  'POST /signup':'UserController.signup',
  'PUT /login': 'UserController.login', 
  'GET /logout':'UserController.logout',
  'GET /profile': 'PageController.showProfilePage', 
  'GET /dashboard': 'PageController.showDashboardPage', 
  'GET /products': 'PageController.showProductPage'

  };
```

Normally the dashboard route exists so what i wanted to do is when i login, i'm automatically redirected to the dashboard. 
So in my UserController.js, i have this:

```
  login : function (req, res){
    //... some code here
            success : function (){
                if(userFound.deleted){
                    return res.forbidden("'Your account has been deleted. 
  Please visit ecommerce.com/restore to restore your account'"); 
                }
                if(userFound.banned){
                    return res.forbidden("'Your account has been banned 
  completly because you didn't respect the use term of our site"); 
                }
                // Store user id in a session
                req.session.userId = userFound.id; 
                console.log(req.session); 
                res.redirect('/dashboard'); 
                return; 
            }
        })
       })
       }
```

And finally, i have my PageController, where i show all the different views of web app based on whether or not the user is authenticated, in this case is dashboard. So , here is what my code says:

```
    showDashboardPage: function (req, res){
       if(!req.session.userId){
          console.log(req.session);
          return res.redirect('/')
       }
    if(req.session.userId){
        User.findOne(req.session.userId, function (err, user){
            if(err){
                console.log(req.session);
                return res.negotiate(err);
            }
            if(!user){
                console.log(req.session);
                sails.log.verbose('Session refers to a user who no longer exist'); 
                return res.redirect('/'); 
            }

            console.log(req.session);
            return res.view('user/dashboard', {
                layout: 'user/mainUserLayout',
                me: {
                    id: user.id, 
                    username: user.username, 
                    fullname: user.fullname,
                    profilePicture: user.profilePicture, 
                    admin: user.admin
                }
            }); 
        });
    }
}
```

When i login , i'm getting a 404 not found error from the server. I don't know if i'm really missing something. Some help will be verry appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're receiving a 404 it's likely that a view you're returning is not at the path you're specified. Have a look at the console log in your browser and check which resource it is that it not found. From here it should be easy for you to deduce the issue. If it is only after you've logged in then my suspicion is that one of your path is incorrect for one of your views.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of request method for login.

```
'PUT /login': 'UserController.login',
```

When you do res.redirect('/dashboard') from login action, it will be a PUT on `/dashboard` which results in 404 since there is no route for PUT /dashboard